# How to automatic click a button on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is silly but I am on a dating site that swipes by clicking a button using getelementbyid.click(). I am attempting to use html code to click the button automatically when body on load but all I can see is a form without id rather than a button, have I misunderstood the code or is there a different code I can use to call a form? Thanks

Comment: please post the code that you can see

Comment: If there is no submit button to click on, but there is a form, use the form's `submit()` method.

Comment: Apologies I thought I have posted the code <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/mutual_match/rate/23797120" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="BmqY/tmrjejao1ACRCM/Ap/AkYU7dOhV7OSO0HjfQXQ="></div>
<input id="rating" name="rating" type="hidden" value="Y">
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Yes">
</form>

Comment: and i think the button is: <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Yes">. Note that it has no Id, this is not my code it is a webpage so I can't give it an ID. I am trying to call the button function programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: To summarise the question is two parts: 1) what should I call, should I be calling the form? 2) the items have no ID, what code can I use. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery trigger() Method when body load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#buttonID").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#Your button').click();
});
</script>
```

this code works on Page load

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("myId").click();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="myId" value="Click Me" onclick="alert(1);"/>
```